# Как урезать размер текстового файла?

Tags: c, c++

Как урезать размер текстового файла? Например в конце файла есть 5 пробелов, как обрезать конец файла на 5 байт?

Comment: Программу, которая делает truncate -s -5 file ? Или truncate -s -7 file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct stat s;
    stat(argv[1], &s);
    truncate(argv[1], s.st_size - 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Так пойдёт?

Comment: alexlz, Напишите пожалуйста пример для конкретного файла. И почемуто мои компилятор не понимает "truncate".  Kомпилятор C-Free 4.0

Comment: В Винде gcc MinGW тоже не понимает. Откройте файл f=fopen(...,"r+") и делайте ftruncate(fileno(f),size)

Comment: Пример для конкретного файла - это содержимое "до" и "после"? Да любое... В приведённом тексте имя файла задаётся первым параметром командной строки argv[1]. Используются юниксовые вызовы, поэтому у Вас их может не быть. У меня WinXP SP2, cygwin. Как это сделать с помощью fopen/fseek/fwrite - затрудняюсь ответить.

Comment: И насчёт mingw - там ограниченная поддержка posix- и/или юниксовых вызовов.

Comment: Если собираете на Windows, то для Windows есть аналог POSIX trancate - это _chsize.

Comment: mingw это, по моему, вообще просто интерфейс с WINAPI (который я и не знаю).

Comment: Не знаете mingw или win32api? Это действительно, как и cygwin & co. интерфейс между posix и win32, но лёгкий, без затей - то, что в win32 отсутствует (напр. fork, select), то и не эмулируется.

Comment: Не знаю win32api. Поэтому с mingw (в отличие от cygwin и interix) иногда сложновато. Кстати, select() там есть, но только для сокетов.
Но у mingw, на мой взгляд, есть неубиваемый плюс - программы получаются автономные, не требуют загрузки dll. Просто переносятся на флэшке и запускаются (ну PATH на новой машине поправить иногда).

Comment: [Offtopic] :) 1. select() в mingw - это select() из winsock. Отсюда и ограничения. 2. Плюс (всё-таки следует упомянуть) отсутствия cygwin1.dll - не в последнюю очередь плюс в лицензировании.[/Offtopic]

Answer (score 2):

Windows-версия:

```
int f;

if (_sopen_s(&f, "filename", _O_RDWR, _SH_DENYNO, _S_IREAD | _S_IWRITE)) {
     _chsize(f, filesize);
     _close(f);
}
```

Comment: Так это по сути ftruncate(). truncate() принимает имя файла.

Comment: @alexl1720p Вам стоит задать новый вопрос, вместо создания комментария: в нем слишком много кода.